# Trouble of AutoML API setup

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, google-vision, automl

I think I have the trouble of AutoML API setup. Please find the following URL

https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tutorial#tutorial-vision-dataset-python

[I'm stuck with the highlight with attach file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q2Uu.jpg)

The step of create

1. I create AutoML service account in GCP with role of AutoML editor and admin
2. I complete the step in the tutorial and stuck with following pass the argument

   ```
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding *project name* -- member=user@domain.com --role=Editor
   ```

The error display in following

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains and invalid argument.
```

Please find the solution for me. Thank you somuch.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the member wrong, you need to change it for it to be the service account you created on step #5 (you need to change what it's between < >) :

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project-id> \
   --member=serviceAccount: <service account you created in step#5> \
   --role='roles/automl.editor'
```

When you see in the documentation the font in pink, it means you need to change that according to your settings (i.e. project id, keys, bucket names). NOTE: this doesn't apply to code itself, as in Python/Java pink means comment.

Comment: The account in the example is Automl service account that I have created in GCP.

Comment: Then you are probably setting something else wrong, like the role. The error says **"Request contains an invalid argument."**, so there has to be something you're sending wrong. Make sure there are no spaces after ":" or "=". If you can't find what's missing from your command, edit your question adding the exact command (of course, changing the project-id and service account name)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add the editor role this is the curl:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project_name --member=serviceAccount:service_account_mail --role="roles/automl.editor"
```

You can also add the editor role via UI, in AI section